# findOneAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've spent all morning googling this, and trying various fixes but I cannot figure it out.

I keep getting the error "TypeError: req.user.findOneAndUpdate is not a function" when I try to run this:

```
req.user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, { $addToSet: { flashcards : { $each: cards }}}, {upsert : true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.send(doc);
    });
```

I've tried explicitly turning req.user into a User model (eg var NewUser = new User(req.body), tried simplifying the query etc but nothing seems to work.

Edit: With model declaration

```
const User = require('../models/user');

var NewUser = new User(req.user);

    NewUser.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, { $addToSet: { flashcards : { $each: cards }}}, {upsert : true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) { return console.log(err); }
        else { return res.send(doc);}
    });
```

User model schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    FlashcardSchema = require('./flashcardSchema'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      password: {
        type: String
      },
      created_on: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
        points: Number,
        flashcards: [FlashcardSchema],
        courses: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course'}]
});

UserSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

And the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    UserSchema = require('../schemas/userSchema');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Are you sure its req.user.findOneAnd... and not just user.findOneAnd...?

Comment: Yeah, it's embedded in a JSON request using Passport :)

Comment: Post your model declaration then.

Comment: Okay I added some more information and changed the req.user into a Model, but the problem persists :(

Comment: Im assuming you already tried User.findOne....?
Cause you are supposed to run it on model and not the instance

Comment: Oh my god. That worked, can you post it as a solution so I can accept it? I really need to take a break from this haha. Thank you so much.

Comment: There you go, added that as a solution :) Glad i helped

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution is to run functions on a model, not on a instance of it. So instead of:

```
var NewUser = new User(req.user);
NewUser.findOneAndUpdate...
```

Do:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate...
```

Comment: Whats the difference between running on an instance and running on model ? could you please share some more details :)

Comment: @UsmanI The `findOneAndUpdate` is just a [static member of the Model class](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L2450). So you need to call it on class itself and not on object.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning after checking err
so

```
req.user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, { $addToSet: { flashcards : { $each: cards }}}, {upsert : true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {return console.log(err);}
        else {return res.send(doc);}
    });
```